# How can I use itertools for a nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm searching for a method to use `itertools.accumulate` in `starmap`.

I tried to calculate the accumulated sum of each row in a table, then concatenate the results to an array:

```py
# my input
my_table = [[3, 5], [1, 4, 7], [2]]
# expected output
P = [3, 8, 1, 5, 12, 2]
```

I use itertools in a for loop, but it becomes much slower than other ways.
So is it possible to use starmap or other itertools method make it quicker?

```py
def getSums(my_table):
    P = []
    for i in range(len(my_table)):
       P.append(itertools.accumulate(my_table[i]))
    P = itertools.chain.from_iterable(P)
    return P
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `starmap` just use built-in `map` function and chain the result using `itertools.chain()`:

```
In [47]: list(chain.from_iterable(map(accumulate, my_table)))
Out[47]: [3, 8, 1, 5, 12, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried your code and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your initial loop approach in a much simplified version, using `extend` which can take any iterable:

```
P = []
for lst in my_table:
    P.extend(accumulate(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Itertools works well, here is what happens under the hood, you can write
your own solutions just use generators(no stdlib needed).

```py
def chain_cumsum(table):
    for it in table:
        yield from cumsum(it)

# write a function to get accumulated sum
def cumsum(l):
    total = 0
    for i in l:
        total += i
        yield total

# then you can get your output:
list(chain_cumsum(my_table))
```